# RuntimeException при получении строки из ресурса и при получении int из аргументов

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Код фрагмента:

```java
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    String s = getString(R.string.mystring);
    final private int n = getArguments().getInt(s, 0);
    //код
}
```

Код в activity:

```java
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt(getString(R.string.my_string), 1);
myFragment.setArguments(b);
```

При инициализации `String s` выбивает ошибку:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{x.a7/x.a7.Main}:
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyFragment{528ec394} not attached to Activity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyFragment{528ec394} not attached to Activity
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:648)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:670)
    at x.a7.MyFragment.<init>(MyFragment.java:44)
    at x.a7.Main.setupViewPager(Main.java:66)
```

Вот такой код во фрагменте тоже выдает ошибку:

```java
final private int n = getArguments().getInt("numb", 0);
```

Логи такой ошибки:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{x.a7/x.a7.Main}:
  java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at x.a7.MyFragment.<init>(MyFragment.java:44)
      at x.a7.Main.setupViewPager(Main.java:66)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызывайте эти методы в `onViewCreated()` например, фрагмент еще не приатачился.